# View only content created by that particular user

Tags: 7

I want the user to view only the content created by him.

Used "content access module". And change permissions for the user to "Grant own Content Access".

But other users also able to see the content created by other users. 
Below is my permissions page:

[image]

Not able to find what went wrong. 
Please correct me.

If any other module is there please suggest me.

Comment: Rebuild permissions and clear cache.. Make sure you dont have any other content access module's installed... it should work !

Comment: @Anil Sagar: Rebuilded Permissions and cleared the cache when installed the content access module. Its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps to resolve the issue !

- Enable Content Access Module
- Clear Cache
- Go to Edit Content Types, and Select Access Control
- Set Access Control As shown below. Remove checkbox view any article content for anonymous and authenticated users.
- Save Settings
- Go to "admin/reports/status/rebuild" and rebuild permissions
- Create a Content of content type that you set access permissions.
- Logout and Login as another normal user and check for access.

Let us know if still fails :-)

[image]

Comment: My mistake didn't do 3 step in your answer. But now its all working.  Thank you.